# How to password protect apps without Jailbreaking iiphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, password

Is there an app for iPhone that allows you to password protect apps without jailbreaking the phone?

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment it's simply not possible within the constraints Apple places on apps. Without jailbreaking, the only way an app could be password protected is if the app developer builds it in. To do otherwise would require modifying the functionality of the parts of the system responsible for launching apps (Springboard), which Apple's rules don't allow, and I suspect that won't change in the foreseeable future, if ever.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly, but you *can* enable parental restrictions with a passcode and deactivate it when you wish to use something. However, this is a very incomplete and impractical solution as it only works on certain stock apps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use/configure this with a specific application?